# NSView redraw not working with setNeedsDisplay:YES;

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, setneedsdisplay

I have a custom view on which I want to force a redraw upon execution of an IBAction method implemented in the NSView controller subclass:

```
- (IBAction)forceRedraw:(id)sender {
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [self display];
}
```

This seems to have no direct effect whatsoever. My custom view only gets redrawn once I mouse into the custom view area or resize the main window.

Any thoughts on why this isn't working?

Comment: How are you determining if it has an effect? What effect would you expect it to have? Are you sure your action method is called?

Comment: I don't normally use view controllers.  I instantiate and add views from within a window controller, so I may be off on this.  But, looking at the docs, it looks like maybe you should say [[self view] setNeedsDisplay:YES]; [[self view] display];.

Comment: Ken, I have code in - (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {} method that is not being executed. I know the forceRedraw method is being called because I put NSLog messages in it.

Comment: jwlaughton, Xcode gives me an error when I do that.

Comment: Update: I found a way to for a redraw, but it seems quite inelegant to me. I created a flag called "force". I set the flag in the forceRedraw method: 

- (IBAction)forceRedraw:(id)sender {
   force = YES;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [self display];
}

then add to following code at the end of the drawRect method:

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
   ... other code

    if (load) {
       [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
        load = NO;
    }
}

The problem now is I don't really understand why that works.

Comment: I wouldn't call "[self display];" directly (it clears the needs display flag)… let the setNeedsDispaly:YES be dispatched thru the runloop.

Comment: Good to know that about [self display]. I will take note of that.